np.zeros and np.arange results different dtype


Why a = np.arange(4.); the result dtype is float,
while a = np.zeros((4.)), was wrong, the error message:  "'float' object cannot be interpreted as an integer"
I understand that np.zeros dtype by default is float, but why  np.zeros((4.))result here refers as integer?
and a = np.zeros((4,)); dtype refers to float again.
So question is : why both np.arange(4.) and np.zeros((4,)) results dtype are float, np.zeros((4.)) here not work?

Please do not upload images of code

The np.zeros dtype has nothing to do with the parameter (shape) you send, that need to be an int or a tuple of ints
shape : int or tuple of ints
        Shape of the new array, e.g., ``(2, 3)`` or ``2``

The parameter you send to np.arange is stop
stop : integer or real
    End of interval. The interval does not include this value, except in some cases
    where step is not an integer and floating point round-off affects the length of out.


Thanks to clear the concepts of np.arange: stop and np.zeros: shape. https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.zeros.html Here mention that numpy.zeros default is float. why the error message mentioned that float subject could not be interpret as integer?

@ElizabethShen because the parameter you fill is shape. It has nothing to do with the dtype parameter.  shape determine the size of the array, dtype the type of the values in it.

Or also because np.zeros by definition, has to use "," rather than"."? as  np.zeros((4,)) works?

@ElizabethS 4. is a float, (4,) is a tuple. You need to use int or tuple of ints.

Got it, thanks a lot
